# Get body selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am using selenium to get html page element:

Here is the code :

```
#First we start by adding the incognito argument to our webdriver.
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/driver/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=option)
browser.get("http://extracts.blalal.com/blla?blalan=vb%20d")
browser.page_source
```

What I have is :

```
'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"Extracts":[],"NextPageUrl":"","PageCount":0}</pre></body></html>'
```

What I want is :

```
{"Extracts":[],"NextPageUrl":"","PageCount":0}
```

Sorry for my novice question, I have tried

Answer (score 2):

Try to get required content as

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('pre').text
```

If you want to use it as Python dict, you might need

```
import json

json.loads(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('pre').text)
```

Comment: I was going to recommend converting the `page_source()` response string to xml and then iterating through it's elements, but this was better. Totally forgot about `find_element_by_tag_name` function. +1